# Minimum distance between photons after attenuation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, photons

Light from a 1 mW He-Ne laser is attenuated by a factor of $10^{11}$. Estimate the minimum distance between the photons.

What does it mean by the minimum distance between photons? As I understood, the attenuation will affect the number of photons but how does it relate to the distance between photons? I started studying Quantum Physics recently.

Comment: Are you given the output power of the laser before attenuation?

Comment: Yes, it is 1 mW.

Comment: I suspect it is an error and they don't want the minimum distance between photons. They want the average (mean) distance between photons.

Comment: You need more information than this to obtain any facts about photon spacing, even if you guess that they mean a common 632.8nm He-Ne laser (others exist). If that's the complete question, I'd treat it literally. The literal question does have a single correct answer, although it has nothing to do with the first sentence.